# How to supply additional audit data to ProgressTracker at runtime

Tags: corda

We have requirement where we would like to supply some additional audit data to progress tracker at runtime. Currently progress tracker shows the static label text when the flow is tracked. I do see that Corda provided some provision in the ProgressTracker.Step class with attribute called extraAuditData. But I don't have an example how to make a use of it.

Answer (score 0):

Progress tracker is a good tool see the process inside the node shell, however, it is not the case that you will always run all of your flows in the node shell.

In a real production environment, you would probably run the flows via some client server, That said, I suggest you use the logger to log any additional information to the log (for debugging).

See example syntax:

```
        log.info("Tracking new Payment Request")
```

Full code: https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/blob/master/Features/cordaService-autopayroll/workflows-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/examples/autopayroll/flows/AutoPaymentService.kt#L26